# Android USB connection is quite weak

Tags: android, bluetooth, usb

When I connect a device to Android phone with USB cable, I'm getting quite poor results.
The phone is the USB host, the baud rate is about 460 Kbit/sec, and the packets size the device sends to the phone is about 1000 bytes.
I'm using the library felHR85:UsbSerial to make things easier.
The problems are:

1. About 1 of 20 packets do not arrive properly from the the device to the phone, and I have to request them. How can I reduce this lost?
2. Every packet transmitted from the device to the phone arrives broken to chunks of 64 or 128 bytes, and I have to compose those packets in my App to get full packet. Can I cause Android to receive the full packet at once?
3. In highr baud rates things get worse. What can I do with it?
4. In Bluetooth the loss ratio with the same device is much lower. Why is Bluetooth connection better than USB connection in Android?

Comment: You may want to state what kind of device/serial chipset you are using. Do read the notes in other Android USB serial libraries like: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/wiki/FAQ#how-to-size-the-read-buffer

Comment: The chipset I'm using in CP210x (probably CP2102). Thanks for your comment.